# Aurelia Nested repeats of objects

Tags: aurelia

Can inner repeat access values of outer repeat and how exactly?
Here is an example I am experimenting with:

```
this.headers = [
                   {text: 'Head 1', value: 'Col1'},
                   {text: 'Head 2', value: 'Col2'},
                   {text: 'Head 3', value: 'Col3'},
               ];
this.tableData = [
                     {'Col1': 1.1, 'Col2': 1.2, 'Col3': 1.3},
                     {'Col1': 2.1, 'Col2': 2.2, 'Col3': 2.3},
                     {'Col1': 3.1, 'Col2': 3.2, 'Col3': 3.3},
                     {'Col1': 4.1, 'Col2': 4.2, 'Col3': 4.3},
                 ];
```

`tableData` is generated dynamicly based on the `headers`

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th repeat.for="head of headers">${head.text}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="line of tableData">
            <td repeat.for="head of $parent.headers">
                ${$parent.line[head.value]}
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All i get back is empty table body

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
            <td></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What am i doing wrong????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange.  I set up a plunkr to investigate, but it seems to work as you pasted above.

http://embed.plnkr.co/kpZOLw/preview

Comment: Thanks Mike for some unknown reason my codes are working as expected now

Comment: It will not work, unless you `believe` that it works. :)